# How can I make scene transitions pass values to the initializer of target class?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

So, I am a bit confused about how to implement the following behavior with cocos2d:

Imagine, a user is on a "Level Select" scene... They choose the appropriate level they want to start on, and tap to begin.. This initiates:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[Game scene] withColor:ccBLACK]];
```

--- but.. How am I supposed to give Game the information about what level the user selected? I was looking through the cocos code, and I don't see any thing allowing one to declare a custom init method with arguments for the class.. So I am just curious what the conventional way to solve this problem is?

To be super clear, I want something like:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[Game scene] performSelector:@selector(initWithLevel) withObject:userLevel withColor:ccBLACK]];
```

which would then call Game's initWithLevel: instead of the default init method (that it appears +node calls)... Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can't you use notifications or delegates for this like we conventionally do in such situations?

Comment: I don't know... what would that look like in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a @property to your Game class that takes the level selected by the user. I'm assuming it's a simple integer number. Then initialize the Game class with the scene class method, set the property, and use it in the transition.

It really helps to **not** cram multiple lines into one. That way those possibilities start jumping right in your face:

```
// initialize your game class
Game* scene = [Game scene];
scene.userSelectedLevel = 10;

// or alternatively:
[scene setUserSelectedLevel:10];

// then transition
CCTransitionScene* transi = [CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 
                                                               scene:scene
                                                           withColor:ccBLACK]
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transi];
```

You can also change your Game class' scene method to take this parameter as input, but frankly just using a property is easier:

```
+(id) sceneWithLevelNumber:(int)levelNumber
{
    // assign level number to Game instance here
}

// call it like this:
[Game sceneWithLevelNumber:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we use one static/single instance of main class...
Now create MyGame class to maintain game specific data like - score, level..
You can access this class in anywhere in the screen..mainmenu, level selection, game screen..

In MyGame.h file

```
@interface MyGame : NSObject
{
    int mLevel;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) int         level;
+ (MyGame *)sharedGameObject;
@end
```

In MyGame.m file

```
static MyGame *gGame = nil;

@implementation MyGame
  @synthesize level = mLevel;


+(MyGame*)sharedGameObject
{
    if(!gGame)
    {
        gGame = [[MyGame alloc] init];
    }
    return gGame;
}

@end
```

//In level selection screen

```
[MyGame sharedGameObject].level = 5;//selected level
```

//In game screen,

```
int level = [MyGame sharedGameObject].level ;
```